# I am trying to get a for loop to compare 2 values edit it accordingly, but it is not working

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-for-loop

```
# 1st loop iterates through user sentence list
for value in user_sentence:
    # iterates through words_dict dictionary, the key is compared and the value is what replace value
    for i in words_dict:  
        if value == i:
            value = words_dict[i]
print(user_sentence[1])
```

I do not understand why the nested for loop is not working, when I change `user_sentence[1]` directly it works, but when I put it in the nested loop it does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are assigning it to `value` variable, not to the list item. You can iterate through the index, and value of the `user_sentence` list using `enumerate`, then modify the value at current index if `value` equals `i`.

```py
# 1st loop iterates through user sentence list
for idx,value in enumerate(user_sentence):
    # iterates through words_dict dictionary, the key is compared and the value is what replace value
    for i in words_dict:  
        if value == i:
            user_sentence[idx] = words_dict[i]
            #break
print(user_sentence[1])
```

On a side note, you can `break` the inner loop which I've commented in above code snippet. It'll just exit the inner loop after finding the first match, this way, you don't need to run loop for all the dictionary items.

Comment: so does that mean that when I use for value in list: that value is not the actual value in the list? it is just a copy?

Comment: When you use `for value in list`, it will assign value from the list iteratively to the `value` variable which has nothing to do  with the actual list, so modifying it will make no changes to the actual list, you need to do it via `index`.